# how restructure data by composite value as a percentage in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Sample of my dataset:

```
tree=structure(list(vyd = c(108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L), date = c("08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018"), row = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), col = c(25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 25L, 26L, 27L), B1 = c(10987, 10987, 10987, 10987, 
11077, 11077, 11077, 11077, 10802, 10802, 11077, 11077, 11077
), B2 = c(10368, 10336, 10400, 10472, 10272, 10312, 10368, 10408, 
10296, 10208, 10192, 10216, 10344), B3 = c(9584, 9496, 9520, 
9456, 9520, 9520, 9496, 9384, 9528, 9304, 9624, 9568, 9464), 
    B4 = c(10136, 9920, 9904, 9936, 10000, 9792, 9824, 9896, 
    9712, 9592, 9904, 9904, 9856), B5 = c(10463, 10463, 10472, 
    10472, 10471, 10471, 10359, 10359, 10162, 9978, 10471, 10471, 
    10359), B6 = c(10173, 10173, 9980, 9980, 10114, 10114, 10036, 
    10036, 9866, 9553, 10114, 10114, 10036), B7 = c(9886, 9886, 
    9733, 9733, 9851, 9851, 9703, 9703, 9504, 9266, 9851, 9851, 
    9703), B8 = c(10456, 10416, 10528, 10416, 10432, 10576, 10592, 
    10384, 10432, 10184, 10528, 10664, 10592), B8A = c(9814, 
    9814, 9592, 9592, 9796, 9796, 9598, 9598, 9283, 9017, 9796, 
    9796, 9598), B9 = c(13463, 13463, 13463, 13463, 13689, 13689, 
    13689, 13689, 13254, 13254, 13689, 13689, 13689), B10 = c(7416, 
    7416, 7323, 7323, 7373, 7373, 7271, 7271, 7072, 6961, 7373, 
    7373, 7271), B11 = c(6244, 6244, 6057, 6057, 6148, 6148, 
    6003, 6003, 5790, 5742, 6148, 6148, 6003), B12 = c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Y = c("5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", 
    "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", 
    "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", "5E3C2B+OC", 
    "5E3C2B+OC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L
))
```

Here `Y` variable has composite value , for example `5E3C2B+OC`.

How to restructure the data so that for each composite value there is the same separate dataset, and the composite value itself becomes a percentage?

for example here 5E,3C,2B (Everything after the plus, we never touch ) 5E=50%E ,3C=30%C, 2B=20%.

Thus, this dataset should be duplicated three times, where two new columns are added together - the letter component and its percentage component.
well, for example, it would look like this (slightly shortened for clarity ).

```
vyd date    row col B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B8A B9  B10 B11 B12 Y   Letter  perc
108 08.01.2018  3   25  10987.0 10368.0 9584.0  10136.0 10463.0 10173.0 9886.0  10456.0 9814.0  13463.0 7416.0  6244.0  1.0 5Е3С2B+ОС   E   50
108 08.01.2018  3   26  10987.0 10336.0 9496.0  9920.0  10463.0 10173.0 9886.0  10416.0 9814.0  13463.0 7416.0  6244.0  1.0 5Е3С2B+ОС   E   50
    ……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….                               ….. NNN                                 
108 08.01.2018  3   25  10987.0 10368.0 9584.0  10136.0 10463.0 10173.0 9886.0  10456.0 9814.0  13463.0 7416.0  6244.0  1.0 5Е3С2B+ОС   C   30
108 08.01.2018  3   26  10987.0 10336.0 9496.0  9920.0  10463.0 10173.0 9886.0  10416.0 9814.0  13463.0 7416.0  6244.0  1.0 5Е3С2B+ОС   C   30
    ……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….                               ….. NNN                                 
108 08.01.2018  3   25  10987.0 10368.0 9584.0  10136.0 10463.0 10173.0 9886.0  10456.0 9814.0  13463.0 7416.0  6244.0  1.0 5Е3С2B+ОС   B   20
108 08.01.2018  3   26  10987.0 10336.0 9496.0  9920.0  10463.0 10173.0 9886.0  10416.0 9814.0  13463.0 7416.0  6244.0  1.0 5Е3С2B+ОС   B   20
```

or desired result via `dput():`

```
Desired_result=structure(list(vyd = c(108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L), 
    date = c("08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
    "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
    "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
    "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
    "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
    "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
    "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
    "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018"
    ), row = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), col = c(25L, 
    26L, 27L, 28L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L), B1 = c(10987, 10987, 10987, 10987, 11077, 11077, 
    11077, 11077, 10802, 10802, 11077, 11077, 11077, 10987, 10987, 
    10987, 10987, 11077, 11077, 11077, 11077, 10802, 10802, 11077, 
    11077, 11077, 10987, 10987, 10987, 10987, 11077, 11077, 11077, 
    11077, 10802, 10802, 11077, 11077, 11077), B2 = c(10368, 
    10336, 10400, 10472, 10272, 10312, 10368, 10408, 10296, 10208, 
    10192, 10216, 10344, 10368, 10336, 10400, 10472, 10272, 10312, 
    10368, 10408, 10296, 10208, 10192, 10216, 10344, 10368, 10336, 
    10400, 10472, 10272, 10312, 10368, 10408, 10296, 10208, 10192, 
    10216, 10344), B3 = c(9584, 9496, 9520, 9456, 9520, 9520, 
    9496, 9384, 9528, 9304, 9624, 9568, 9464, 9584, 9496, 9520, 
    9456, 9520, 9520, 9496, 9384, 9528, 9304, 9624, 9568, 9464, 
    9584, 9496, 9520, 9456, 9520, 9520, 9496, 9384, 9528, 9304, 
    9624, 9568, 9464), B4 = c(10136, 9920, 9904, 9936, 10000, 
    9792, 9824, 9896, 9712, 9592, 9904, 9904, 9856, 10136, 9920, 
    9904, 9936, 10000, 9792, 9824, 9896, 9712, 9592, 9904, 9904, 
    9856, 10136, 9920, 9904, 9936, 10000, 9792, 9824, 9896, 9712, 
    9592, 9904, 9904, 9856), B5 = c(10463, 10463, 10472, 10472, 
    10471, 10471, 10359, 10359, 10162, 9978, 10471, 10471, 10359, 
    10463, 10463, 10472, 10472, 10471, 10471, 10359, 10359, 10162, 
    9978, 10471, 10471, 10359, 10463, 10463, 10472, 10472, 10471, 
    10471, 10359, 10359, 10162, 9978, 10471, 10471, 10359), B6 = c(10173, 
    10173, 9980, 9980, 10114, 10114, 10036, 10036, 9866, 9553, 
    10114, 10114, 10036, 10173, 10173, 9980, 9980, 10114, 10114, 
    10036, 10036, 9866, 9553, 10114, 10114, 10036, 10173, 10173, 
    9980, 9980, 10114, 10114, 10036, 10036, 9866, 9553, 10114, 
    10114, 10036), B7 = c(9886, 9886, 9733, 9733, 9851, 9851, 
    9703, 9703, 9504, 9266, 9851, 9851, 9703, 9886, 9886, 9733, 
    9733, 9851, 9851, 9703, 9703, 9504, 9266, 9851, 9851, 9703, 
    9886, 9886, 9733, 9733, 9851, 9851, 9703, 9703, 9504, 9266, 
    9851, 9851, 9703), B8 = c(10456, 10416, 10528, 10416, 10432, 
    10576, 10592, 10384, 10432, 10184, 10528, 10664, 10592, 10456, 
    10416, 10528, 10416, 10432, 10576, 10592, 10384, 10432, 10184, 
    10528, 10664, 10592, 10456, 10416, 10528, 10416, 10432, 10576, 
    10592, 10384, 10432, 10184, 10528, 10664, 10592), B8A = c(9814, 
    9814, 9592, 9592, 9796, 9796, 9598, 9598, 9283, 9017, 9796, 
    9796, 9598, 9814, 9814, 9592, 9592, 9796, 9796, 9598, 9598, 
    9283, 9017, 9796, 9796, 9598, 9814, 9814, 9592, 9592, 9796, 
    9796, 9598, 9598, 9283, 9017, 9796, 9796, 9598), B9 = c(13463, 
    13463, 13463, 13463, 13689, 13689, 13689, 13689, 13254, 13254, 
    13689, 13689, 13689, 13463, 13463, 13463, 13463, 13689, 13689, 
    13689, 13689, 13254, 13254, 13689, 13689, 13689, 13463, 13463, 
    13463, 13463, 13689, 13689, 13689, 13689, 13254, 13254, 13689, 
    13689, 13689), B10 = c(7416, 7416, 7323, 7323, 7373, 7373, 
    7271, 7271, 7072, 6961, 7373, 7373, 7271, 7416, 7416, 7323, 
    7323, 7373, 7373, 7271, 7271, 7072, 6961, 7373, 7373, 7271, 
    7416, 7416, 7323, 7323, 7373, 7373, 7271, 7271, 7072, 6961, 
    7373, 7373, 7271), B11 = c(6244, 6244, 6057, 6057, 6148, 
    6148, 6003, 6003, 5790, 5742, 6148, 6148, 6003, 6244, 6244, 
    6057, 6057, 6148, 6148, 6003, 6003, 5790, 5742, 6148, 6148, 
    6003, 6244, 6244, 6057, 6057, 6148, 6148, 6003, 6003, 5790, 
    5742, 6148, 6148, 6003), B12 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Y = c("5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", 
    "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", 
    "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", 
    "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", 
    "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", 
    "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", 
    "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", "5E3C2B", 
    "5E3C2B"), Letter = c("E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), perc = c(50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -39L))
```

If there are any other rows with other composite values, do the same for them. For example, if rows appeared where Y in `4o6b`, then two columns of letter O= 40% and B=60% will appear according to the same principle as I described above. (I.E 2 times the dataset is duplicated With different letters )

How to do such reformation of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse`. Add three new columns to the right

```
library(tidyverse)
tree %>% 
  separate(Y, into = c("E", "C", "B"), sep=c(1,3,5), remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(C, B), ~str_remove_all(., "[A-Z]"))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(E, C, B), ~as.numeric(.)*10))
   vyd       date row col    B1    B2   B3    B4    B5    B6   B7    B8  B8A    B9  B10  B11 B12         Y  E  C  B
1  108 08.01.2018   3  25 10987 10368 9584 10136 10463 10173 9886 10456 9814 13463 7416 6244   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
2  108 08.01.2018   3  26 10987 10336 9496  9920 10463 10173 9886 10416 9814 13463 7416 6244   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
3  108 08.01.2018   3  27 10987 10400 9520  9904 10472  9980 9733 10528 9592 13463 7323 6057   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
4  108 08.01.2018   3  28 10987 10472 9456  9936 10472  9980 9733 10416 9592 13463 7323 6057   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
5  108 08.01.2018   4  25 11077 10272 9520 10000 10471 10114 9851 10432 9796 13689 7373 6148   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
6  108 08.01.2018   4  26 11077 10312 9520  9792 10471 10114 9851 10576 9796 13689 7373 6148   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
7  108 08.01.2018   4  27 11077 10368 9496  9824 10359 10036 9703 10592 9598 13689 7271 6003   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
8  108 08.01.2018   4  28 11077 10408 9384  9896 10359 10036 9703 10384 9598 13689 7271 6003   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
9  108 08.01.2018   4  29 10802 10296 9528  9712 10162  9866 9504 10432 9283 13254 7072 5790   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
10 108 08.01.2018   4  30 10802 10208 9304  9592  9978  9553 9266 10184 9017 13254 6961 5742   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
11 108 08.01.2018   5  25 11077 10192 9624  9904 10471 10114 9851 10528 9796 13689 7373 6148   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
12 108 08.01.2018   5  26 11077 10216 9568  9904 10471 10114 9851 10664 9796 13689 7373 6148   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
13 108 08.01.2018   5  27 11077 10344 9464  9856 10359 10036 9703 10592 9598 13689 7271 6003   1 5E3C2B+OC 50 30 20
```

Or three duplicated rows using that

```
tree %>% 
  mutate(Y1=str_replace_all(Y, "[A-Z]", "_"))  %>% 
  mutate(Y2=str_replace_all(Y, "[0-9]", "_") %>% str_remove(., "_")) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Y1, Y2), ~str_sub(., 1,5))) %>% 
  separate_rows(Y1, Y2, sep="_") %>% 
  mutate(Y1 = as.numeric(Y1)*10)
     vyd date         row   col    B1    B2    B3    B4    B5    B6    B7    B8   B8A    B9   B10   B11   B12 Y            Y1 Y2   
   <int> <chr>      <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>
 1   108 08.01.2018     3    25 10987 10368  9584 10136 10463 10173  9886 10456  9814 13463  7416  6244     1 5E3C2B+OC    50 E    
 2   108 08.01.2018     3    25 10987 10368  9584 10136 10463 10173  9886 10456  9814 13463  7416  6244     1 5E3C2B+OC    30 C    
 3   108 08.01.2018     3    25 10987 10368  9584 10136 10463 10173  9886 10456  9814 13463  7416  6244     1 5E3C2B+OC    20 B    
 4   108 08.01.2018     3    26 10987 10336  9496  9920 10463 10173  9886 10416  9814 13463  7416  6244     1 5E3C2B+OC    50 E    
 5   108 08.01.2018     3    26 10987 10336  9496  9920 10463 10173  9886 10416  9814 13463  7416  6244     1 5E3C2B+OC    30 C    
 6   108 08.01.2018     3    26 10987 10336  9496  9920 10463 10173  9886 10416  9814 13463  7416  6244     1 5E3C2B+OC    20 B    
 7   108 08.01.2018     3    27 10987 10400  9520  9904 10472  9980  9733 10528  9592 13463  7323  6057     1 5E3C2B+OC    50 E    
 8   108 08.01.2018     3    27 10987 10400  9520  9904 10472  9980  9733 10528  9592 13463  7323  6057     1 5E3C2B+OC    30 C    
 9   108 08.01.2018     3    27 10987 10400  9520  9904 10472  9980  9733 10528  9592 13463  7323  6057     1 5E3C2B+OC    20 B    
10   108 08.01.2018     3    28 10987 10472  9456  9936 10472  9980  9733 10416  9592 13463  7323  6057     1 5E3C2B+OC    50 E    
# ... with 29 more rows
```